# Keep element on horizontal point on window on resize

Tags: jquery, css, window-resize

I have two elements, one is container, width 1245px, relative position and centered relatively to window (with grey background-opacity 0.3)
Second is absolute div (#grey-left), simple rectangle, which must be behind container, it must be positioned to the left of window, right point of element must be behind container.

To simplify... width of rectangle where these two elements interact, must always be the same, regardless of window size! And because container width is fixed, a #grey-left must change width relatively to window width.

Is it possible with CSS, if not jQuery.

Code:

```
#grey-left{
    height: 420px;
    top: 84px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: ?? ;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1245px;  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a live example here ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/28N5z/1/

Note that the width of #grey-left div, should not be fixed. The width of "rectangle" that is created on intersection should be.

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected output. Can you draw a picture to show how the divs should be positioned ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/54x4z5qvd/
hope it helps :) ty
red text width is the one that souldn't change on resize. Also container width shouldn't change... Only #grey-left is resizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it, without resorting to JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/28N5z/3/

HTML

```
<div id="grey-left">
    <div class="wrapper">
        Perhaps you want some content in here?
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
    width: 1245px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#grey-left {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
#grey-left .wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

The basic technique is to give `#grey-left` a large width, and offset it against the centre of the window. You then need to hide horizontal overflow to avoid a scrollbar using `overflow-x: hidden`.

You can delete `.wrapper` and its styles if you don't need any content in there.